# BlackBerry - How can i Hide Video Field

Tags: blackberry, java-me, flashlight

**working on blackberry OS7 9850 device**

i am working to Turn on Flash as Light on Blackberry.

i have successfully completed this, but in BBOS6 device 9780 video field is showing; how can i hide that video field?

here is my code

```
private FlashControl flashControl;
private VideoControl _videoControl;
private Field _videoField;
private ButtonField capture;
private Field videoField;

    // Set the displayed title of the screen       
    public MyScreen(int j) {


        try {

            Player player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?encoding=video/3gpp");

            player.realize();

            VideoControl videoControl = (VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl");
            if(videoControl != null)
            {
                videoField = (Field)videoControl.initDisplayMode( VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field" );
                try
                {

                    videoControl.setDisplaySize(1, 1);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
                //videoControl.setDisplaySize( 0 , 0 );
                videoControl.setVisible(true);
                videoField.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0x000000));
                //videoField.
                add(videoField);

                flashControl = (FlashControl)player.getControl("javax.microedition.amms.control.camera.FlashControl");
                setFlashlight(true);
            }
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void setFlashlight(boolean b) {

        if(b == true){
            flashControl.setMode(FlashControl.FORCE);
        }
        else{
            flashControl.setMode(FlashControl.OFF);
        }
    }
```

is there any solution, like we can push the screen or video field in the background?

Answer (score 2):

There is (at least) one app on BlackBerry World (e.g. *One Touch Flashlight*) that does this, and it almost certainly accomplishes this task in the following way (instead of using `VideoControl` and `FlashControl`):

1. The app programmatically opens the native **Camera** app
2. Using keystroke injection, the app injects touch events to turn on the camera's flash
3. The app then requests the foreground back ([Application#requestForeground()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#requestForeground())), so that it covers up the **Camera** app.
4. When you close the app, it overrides [Screen#onClose()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onClose()) and takes the opportunity to inject another `Characters.ESCAPE` key event, which also closes out the Camera app, which was simply behind the foregrounded "flashlight" app.

You can search Stack Overflow for other examples of opening **Camera** from your app, using keystroke injection, and requesting your app be brought to the foreground.

### References

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559836/119114

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1298900/119114

http://www.blackberry.com/go/toucheventinjectorsampleapp

Comment: thanks for giving suggestion any how i have manage to hide video field for few second by giving this code UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new nextscreen());
                      }
                  }, 100, false); now i want to close current screen after turning flash light on how can i do this.

Comment: and this is nextscreen clas  public nextscreen() 
        {
            setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.BLACK, 250));
           
        }
        protected void paint(net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics graphics) 
        {
            super.subpaint(graphics);
        }

Comment: @askquestion, please don't post new questions down here in comments.  Your comments don't seem to have anything to do with the solution I suggested in my answer.  You are free to post new questions if you like.  Please also don't paste unformatted code into comments.  I can't read that.  Can you?